# Not all documents are being indexed by cognitive search using SharePoint as a datasource

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-cognitive-search

I've set up an index and indexer in Azure Cognitive Search, using a SharePoint teams site as my data source. I've realised today that even when I remove all document type filtering, it's not adding all my documents to the index. I'm aware some of them are file types not handled by SharePoint, but some of these are still appearing in the index, just without any usable data.

Is this something anyone else has experienced? Does anyone know how to fix it? It's about 150 documents, and short of manually cross-referencing 900 documents I don't have a good way to tell if there's a unifying factor causing these 150 to be skipped or if it's just a quirk of the feature still being in preview?

Comment: the best way is to write yourself the code to extract the content and push it to Azure Cognitive Search. It's possible that the indexer is throwing an error during the indexing process

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Where would you suggest I start with it? It's not showing any errors, it just seems to be random documents?

Comment: if there are no errors, there's nothing you can do. You'd better go with my other suggestion and write your own 'indexer'

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer to this, it turns out that there's a limit on the size of files the indexer will handle which is dictated by tier the indexer is provisioned at. The mystery missing files were larger than the size the tier would accept.